# How do I display information from a form?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, repository

I am trying to display information submitted from a form to create a message board.  I am using php in the laravel framework.  I am using a form, record, and repository.  Whenever I try to display the content I receive the following error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Here is the controller:

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /messages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('comments.create');
}



 public function show($comment)
{
    $message_id = $this->messageRepository->find($comment);
    return View::make('comments.show')->with('comment', $message_id);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 * POST /messaages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::all() ;
    $this->messageForm->validate($data);

    $messageRecord = new MessageRecord;
    $messageRecord->comment = $data['comment'];

    Return "Comment created";
}
}
```

Here is the view causing the trouble:

```
<p>$comment</p>
```

I have not been using a route but I threw this together:

```
Route::resource('/message', 'MessageController');
```

Comment: The error message is indicative of an incorrect route to the controller method.  Can you also supply the content of routes.php?

Comment: i don't have a route for it because both are being through an established page with its own routes.

Comment: Like watcher said, updating your post with the routes.php file will clear things up so we can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use incorrect verb for route displaying this route. For `display` you should probably use `Route::get` and you probably use `Route::post`. If it's not the issue you edit your question and put there `routes.php` as you were asked in comment.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit:]**

If your `store()` is already used by another form and you still have another form to send POST data then, you should declare another routes for that. Like

```
Route::post('message/display', ['as' => 'message.display', 'uses' => 'MessageController@display');
```

Sorry for my previous answer,  `show()` is for GET request and since you are using form you probably you don't need it unless you decide to send data through url. I'm extremely sorry.

**[Edit ends]**

You are getting that error because you are not allowed to use `display()` in resourceful routing. Instead, you must use `store()`. Since you are using laravel resourceful routing, you should follow the convention of laravel. In your command line, run

```
php artisan routes
```

You will get something like this,

```
    GET|HEAD message                | message.index   | MessageController@index
    GET|HEAD message/create         | message.create  | MessageController@create
    POST message                    | message.store   | MessageController@store
    GET|HEAD message/{message}      | message.show    | MessageController@show
    GET|HEAD message/{message}/edit | message.edit    | MessageController@edit
    PUT message/{message}           | message.update  | MessageController@update
    PATCH message/{message}         |                 | MessageController@update
    DELETE message/{message}        | message.destroy | MessageController@destroy
```

These are the methods, their route names and their corresponding HTTP request that you should use.

[Check Laravel documentation for resourceful controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

For quick look,

```
index : Display a listing of the resource,
create : Show the form for creating a new resource, 
store : Store a newly created resource in storage,
show : Display the specified resource,
edit : Show the form for editing the specified resource,
update : Update the specified resource in storage,
destroy : Remove the specified resource from storage
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sending POST or GET request to show method?  It should be GET request.

Comment: i am just using a general resource

Comment: I read you question carefully. Since you are trying to display details submitted through form using POST request, you must use `store()` method instead of `show`.

Comment: For what purpose are you using `store()`? Unless you define another dedicated route and a method, `store()` will be the only method that accepts POST data in resourceful routing.